# How to use group by and sum in Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, backend

I have a JSON array that contains objects like this one

```
 {
            "InvoiceNo": "FA 2019/1",
            "Period": "01",
            "DocumentTotals": {
                "TaxPayable": "26.94",
                "NetTotal": "117.16",
                "GrossTotal": "144.10"
            },
            "WithholdingTax": {
                "WithholdingTaxAmount": "0.00"
            }
        },
```

I want to sum the GrossTotal of the various objects and group it by Period.
I tried with the following code:

```
saftFileController.revenuePerMonth = function (req, res) {
  Saft.find().exec(function (err, fileContent) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      const JSONObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(fileContent));
      const sales = JSONObject[3].SalesInvoices.Invoice;
      const revenuePerMonth = Saft.aggregate([
        {
          $group: {
            Period: sales.Period,
            revenue: {
              $sum: "$GrossTotal",
            },
          },
        },
      ]);
      res.json({ revenue: revenuePerMonth });
    }
  });
};
```

But the output wasn´t the desired one. What I am doing wrong? This was the output:

```
{
    "revenue": {
        "_pipeline": [
            {
                "$group": {
                    "revenue": {
                        "$sum": "$GrossTotal"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "options": {}
    }
}
```

Here are some printscreens of my Database

https://snipboard.io/QOfiYz.jpg

https://snipboard.io/72LSRC.jpg

Did this and now returns the Period but it is ignoring the sum because it is a string type.How can I convert?

```
saftFileController.revenuePerMonth = function (req, res) {
  Saft.aggregate([
    {
      $group: {
        _id: "$SalesInvoices.Invoice.Period",
        revenue: {
          $sum: "SalesInvoices.Invoice.DocumentTotals.GrossTotal",
        },
      },
    },
  ]).exec(function (err, fileContent) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error: ", error);
    } else {
      res.json({ revenuePerMonth: fileContent });
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You should pass the MongoDB expression what you want to group it by as `_id` in the `$group` stage ([documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)). The $sum expression should contain the full path as well.

```
          $group: {
            _id: '$Period',
            revenue: {
              $sum: "$DocumentTotals.GrossTotal",
            },
          },
```

2. aggregate accepts a callback, or returns a `Promise` just like when you use `Saft.find()`

```
Saft.aggregate([/* ... */]).exec(function (err, result) {
  /* use result here */
})
```

Comment: This ia a silly question. The information That I want to aggregate is only in the array Invoice that is present in the third oject of my database. So in the agreggate should I use Invoice .Period?

Comment: How does the array `Invoice` look like? If it's present only in one object you could just calculate in node.js, no need for MongoDB aggregation. Not sure that I under stood correctly though

Comment: I updated my question with printscreens of my Database, maybe it is easier to explain wit h it

Comment: ignore the edits in your answer, I made it by mistake

Comment: Looks like your collection doesn't have any schema. Aggregation is intended to target multiple documents in the same collection. It is possible to do it with MongoDB Aggregation, but it doesn't make much sense .If you already have the document you can just calculate it in node.js by iterating over `JSONObject[3].SalesInvoices.Invoice` or use `array.reduce()`.